# Updating database properties automatically in Spring using hibernate after modifying a property on the model

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a spring application that after creating the database from the back end and launch the application, it runs a migration and creates the corresponding entities. This is the sample entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String price;
    private String authors;
    private String isbn;
    private String publisher;
    private Date publishedOn;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

If I delete this field from the entity class for example lets say I don't want it anymore

```
private String publisher;
    private Date publishedOn;
```

**EDITTED**

In my hibernate configuration xml file I have added this to see if the database will be updated accordingly but it didn't

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

On re-launching the application, how can it be done that the database entity from the backend will be updated automatically just as the way the table and the fields was created automatically on first launch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Updating database entities after modifying the model. Which area do you not understand. Tell me the information you need and I will provide you

Comment: Enough with the editing. "Please I need your ideas" and (as far as I can tell) "spring-mvc" don't belong here. Blaze: If you cannot be content with other people editing your posts, you cannot post on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Maby use something like this: (Not tested)

```
<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

So yours would be:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```